# Is a checkin agent able to print an extended baggage tag?

Tags: luggage, europe, airport-transfer

This coming month I will have a connecting flight nightmare - 2 connections, one of them not on the same airline all with tight timings AND a checked bag. Luckily, all this is within Schengen, the last flight being domestic but I have 1:10 hours for my last connection, where i would have to collect my bag and re-check it. To avoid missing my second connection (third flight) am I able to ask the checkin agent at BUD to print me a tag all the way to the end of the itinerary?

[image]

I did call Lufthansa already, but they weren't the most helpful bunch, probably also because of my bad way of phrasing the question. Obviously the original bag tag would be BUD-VIE-CPH, but can I ask the checkin agent at BUD to also add on the SGD part, with all the necessary info about the flight?

Comment: You want Lufthansa to print a bag tag for a different airline, on a different booking? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: more to the line of adding the last part on there. Not sure if that's possible - phone customer service said it should be ok if I ask the agent, just wanted to ask if anyone had similar experiences.

Comment: @KristófGergelyBakos it depends on the agreements between the airlines, it is technically possible but not always the airlines involved have the necessary agreements between them (called interline agreements).

Comment: there's never any harm in asking, but you should be prepared for the answer to be no.

Answer (score 4):

Lufthansa (`LH`) does not have a baggage interline agreement with Air Alsie (`6I`):

```
   MAY CHECK BAGGAGE TO
       AA  AC  AD  AE  AF  AI  AM  AR  AS  AT  AV  AY  AZ  A3  
       BA  BL  BP  BR  BT  B2  B6  CA  CI  CM  CX  CZ  DE  DL  
       DT  EK  EN  ET  EW  EY  E5  FB  FI  FM  FV  GA  GF  GU  
       G3  HA  HO  HR  HU  HX  IB  IC  IG  IR  JE  JJ  JL  JQ  
       JU  J2  KA  KC  KL  KM  KQ  KU  LA  LG  LH  LO  LP  LR  
       LX  LY  ME  MI  MK  MS  MU  NH  NZ  OA  OB  OK  OM  OO  
       OS  OU  OZ  PG  PR  PS  PW  PZ  QF  QI  RO  R7  SA  SB  
       SC  SD  SK  SN  SP  SQ  SV  S3  S4  TA  TG  TK  TN  TP  
       TR  TU  T0  UA  UK  UL  UT  UU  UX  U0  VA  VK  VN  WF  
       WK  WY  W2  XL  XQ  YM  ZH  ZX  2A  2K  3K  4M  4U  4Z
```

Therefore it is very unlikely the check-in agent will be able to print a tag including an Air Alsie flight. If one is printed, it's not clear the bag will be routed correctly.

In times past getting additional flights printed on a label was straightforward (if the carriers interlined to each other): agents knew how to do it and were happy to be helpful. Indeed, alliances like oneworld once made interlined baggage across separate tickets within the alliance it a stated benefit. These days, network airlines in Europe look to minimize costs by delivering a uniform product.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer - I find it a shame that even though bag tags are standard, and from what I've seen mostly just include flight numbers and transitting and arrival airport on them, carriers can't or don't print them like this.

Comment: @KristófGergelyBakos Under Article 36 of the Montréal Convention of 1999, the passenger is entitled to sue both the first and last carriers (at his option) in a baggage journey for loss or damage to his checked bag, regardless of who actually is responsible. Therefore carriers want an agreement in place to indemnify the sued carrier before accepting the liability that comes with interline bags. Also, it's not clear that 6I even has the facilities to accept interline baggage. So there are good reasons why interline agreements are required before the label can be printed.